# VBA Deleting rows in Excel - Loop only for certain worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a loop to find cells with a "0" entry in column B and then delete the entire corresponding rows.

Unfortunately, I am not able to write it so it only works for one specific worksheet. Here's what I got so far:

```
Dim myloop 

For myloop = Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(myloop, 4).Value = 0 Then Rows(myloop).EntireRow.Delete

Next myloop
```

I want this loop specifically to run only for worksheet 2 but not my entire code to run only in worksheet 2 as this loop is just part of a bigger code.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fully qualify your `Range` with a certian `Worksheet`.

**Note**: you could use the `AutoFilter` as well, works faster for large data.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <-- modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
    For myloop = .Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(myloop, 4).Value = 0 Then .Rows(myloop).EntireRow.Delete
    Next myloop
End With
```

**Alternative**: to get the last row with data in Column B (if the data will be more than 10,000 rows)

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <-- modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
    For myloop = .Range("B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B")).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(myloop, 4).Value = 0 Then .Rows(myloop).EntireRow.Delete
    Next myloop
End With
```

Comment: Tried it out and looks as if it is working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if the block of code is within a bigger loop looping through worksheets, Add a if condition (activesheet.index= 2) or just check if the activesheet is sheet2 or if its just a seperate loop then specify the sheet in the code